# Java class design issue

Tags: java, class, methods, visibility

Here is a class design: http://pastebin.com/1RSdmtXi

If i put only `A` to class Expect I would like to see only A's getters and setters, or vica vera to B. If put in `A` and `B`, then all of getters and setters should be visible.

So an example for only `A`:

```
A[] aExampe = {new A("Tim",1)};
Expect exp = new Expect(aExampe);

exp.getA(); --> visible
exp.getB(); --> not visible
```

You may advice another design for this.

Comment: surely this issue - consequence of bad architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class Expect you should only have getA(), setA, getB and setB, not all the getters and setters for A and B's attributes. Those ones belong to those classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
 Expect.class.getMethod("getA", null).setAccessible(true);
 Expect.class.getMethod("getB", null).setAccessible(false);
```

But I suggest you to change your architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Why this is a need?

If you change the class `Expect` (by adding an removing fields), you can add and remove getters and setters too.

If you want to change the class without modifying and recompiling client classes, define an interface containing all needed methods, implement it by `Expect` class, and instead of removing the methods, just make them empty methods (without any body).

By this pattern, you will not use compile time checking, and won't need to use dirty reflection for normal method calls.